# How to handle drop event in Drag and drop of an imageview?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I need drag and drop in my new project. I referred this [blogpost](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/android-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html). But I'm facing a problem while performing Drop. I cannot get the image which I hold and can't drop into view. DragListner which I used is given below. I don't know how to handle the dropevent.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
        int dragAction = dragEvent.getAction();
        View dragView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
        if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {
            System.out.println("exit------------");
            containsDragable = false;
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
            System.out.println("enter------------");
            containsDragable = true;
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
                System.out.println("end------------");
                dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP && containsDragable) {
            dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe at first you can print out the

```
DragEvent.ACTION_DROP
```

code, and compare it to the value of the dragAction .
if the value is the same then the problem are at containsDragable function.

hope this helps